# fullPage.js without easing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js

I would like to use `fullpage.JS` without having a transition between slides. Here's what I tried, with no success:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    licenseKey: 'XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX',
    recordHistory: false,
    easing: 'none'
});
```

Any recommendations on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scrollingSpeed:0`, but that will lead to issues when using the mousewheel to scroll, specially in kinetic scrolling devices such as Apple laptops trackpads.

If you want to use no transitions, I would also recommend to disable the mouse wheel scrolling by calling:

`fullpage_api.setAllowScrolling(false)`.

This way you can still scroll with the keyboard.